# form.$valid false even though values are binded to fields in Edit mode angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to update the data through form but in Edit mode it form.$valid gives false even though binding form elements with values in Edit mode.

Please note that same form is getting used for Create and Edit.

Html

```
<section data-ng-controller="testController" data-ng-init="getData()">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form name="Frm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textinput">Name</label>  
                <div class="col-md-3" show-errors="{ skipFormGroupCheck: true }">
                    <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" data-ng-model="shortName" required>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Controller JS

```
     $scope.create = function() {
                $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity');
    console.log($scope.Frm.$valid);
                if ($scope.Frm.$valid) {
// Do save/Update
            }
    }
```

I'm using below module for validation but it  doens't seem it is causing issue.
https://github.com/paulyoder/angular-bootstrap-show-errors

While I create without loading any Data it works but not in Edit mode of the form.

Please help.

Comment: I think since you are making use of `novalidate`, that is causing the issue.

Comment: its present in while create new entry too. Once the data is filled up it doesn't have any problem.

Comment: Show the demo of your code.